Spring Boot 3.1 to 3.3 upgrade NoClassDefFoundError: RestTemplateExchangeTagsProvider
It seems like this error is coming from some type of auto configuration but not sure how to resolve it.
I can see that these classes were deprecated and now removed but what dependency is trying to use it?
2024-05-14T17:49:47.222Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.observation.web.servlet.WebMvcObservationAutoConfiguration
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:470) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:459) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:131) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:428) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:788) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
 at com.tmobile.steelthread.tfbbulkpublisher.TfbBulkPublisherApplication.main(TfbBulkPublisherApplication.java:20) ~[!/:1.0.31]
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) ~[app.jar:1.0.31]
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) ~[app.jar:1.0.31]
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) ~[app.jar:1.0.31]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.observation.web.client.RestTemplateObservationConfiguration] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.LaunchedClassLoader@50040f0c]
 at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:750) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:749) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:682) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:653) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1676) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:247) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:240) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:183) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:120) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
 ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/client/RestTemplateExchangeTagsProvider
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504) ~[na:na]
 at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
 ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.client.RestTemplateExchangeTagsProvider
 at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592) ~[na:na]
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.net.protocol.jar.JarUrlClassLoader.loadClass(JarUrlClassLoader.java:104) ~[app.jar:1.0.31]
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.LaunchedClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedClassLoader.java:91) ~[app.jar:1.0.31]
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[na:na]
 ... 45 common frames omitted


Found the culprit.
The parent pom was
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </parent>

But in the dependencies, we had:
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.6</version>
 </dependency>

which conflicts with the spring boot parent version. Removing the "version" tag so maven pulls in the correct one based on the parent pom fixed the issue.

According to the Spring documents, this class is deprecated by version 3.0.0 (Here is the link)

RestTemplateExchangeTagsProvider, WebClientExchangeTagsProvider, WebFluxTagsProvider, WebMvcTagsProvider and related classes have been replaced with ObservationConvention equivalents.

And as by 3.2.0 the deprecations are removed. (Here is the link)

Classes, methods, and properties that were deprecated in Spring Boot 3.0 have been removed in this release. Please ensure that you aren’t calling deprecated methods before upgrading.

And spring javadocs for WebClientExchangeTagsProvider states that we should use ClientRequestObservationConvention instead.
